# Passing List into Ansible conditional

Tags: ansible

I have a list of files that I would like to change mode on, but only if they exist.  I was thinking that I could use a combination of `stat` and `with_item`. I'm pretty new to this and any ideas would be a really big help. Thanks, John

```
---
 - hosts: all

   tasks:
 - name: checking if file exists
   stat: path={{ item }}
   register: file_exists
   with_items:
    - /tmp/test1
    - /home/john/test2
    - /home/allison/test3

 - name: change permissions
   file: path={{ item }} mode=0600
   when: file_exists.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work with some modifications:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      permissioned_files:
        - /tmp/test1.txt
        - /home/john/test2
        - /home/allison/test3
    tasks:
    - name: checking if file exists
      stat: path={{ item }}
      register: file_exists
      with_items: "{{ permissioned_files }}"

    - name: change permissions
      file: path={{ item.0 }} mode=0600
      when: "{{ item.1.stat.exists }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ permissioned_files }}"
        - "{{ file_exists.results }}"
```

Changes:

- Fixed indentation
- Added items loop to second task
- Used common variable instead of repeating the list of files
- Used a [parallel loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) to access the listed stat results and the different files where permissions must be set

A simpler solution is to use the `ignore_errors` parameter and current capabilities of the [Ansible file module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html): when state is set to "file" (as it is by default), the module will not create the file. `ignore_errors` means the play will not fail when a task encounters errors.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure one sample file exists
      file:
        path: /tmp/test1.txt
        state: touch

    - name: Change permissions
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        mode: 0600
      with_items:
        - /tmp/test1.txt
        - /home/john/test2
        - /home/allison/test3
      ignore_errors: true
```